# Use bleach to Sanitize all Form input fields in Django

Tags: django, forms, sanitization

I am new to sanitize input fields in django form and need your help. Here is one example for bleaching one field in django form. http://www.agmweb.ca/2010-12-31-django-and-bleach/

My question is, if there are 10 such fields in django ModelForm, is there a better way than bleaching all 10 fields ONE by ONE?

That is, could it just use something like this bleach(form.data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`django-bleach`](https://django-bleach.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#in-your-models) which provides a `BleachField` (wrapper around `models.TextField`):

```
from django import models
from django_bleach.models import BleachField

class Post(models.Model):

    content = BleachField()
```

Or if you want to bleach all fields of your form you could override `_clean_fields()`:

```
class YourForm(ModelForm):

    def _clean_fields(self):
        super(LogCollectorParamsForm, self)._clean_fields()
        for name, value in self.cleaned_data.items():
            self.cleaned_data[name] = bleach.clean(value)
```

Comment: yes, I know this one. However, could bleach just clean all fields by cleaning form.data??

Comment: But what for? What's the point of bleaching integer fields, boolean fields and string fields which do not contain html? Unnecessary overhead!

Comment: I see. Thank you! So, CharField, TextField need it, right? What else?

Comment: @thinkdeep A WYSIWYG editor if you use one.